# SharePoint Meta started accessible for me recently, why?

Tags: discussion

Is there a reason why I was not seeing SharePoint Meta from the day I joined SharePoint stackexchange - 14th Dec 2017 till 17th Jan 2018?

Even I was in impression there is no Meta here. I think its not based on Reputation. Am I missing something basic? (Getting old maybe :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Participate in Meta is awarded at 5 Reputation

**Why do I need 5 rep to post there?**

Your reputation on meta is the same as your reputation on the parent site.

You can always read meta with no rep at all.

Because we allow anonymous participation, we require a small bit of parent site reputation to prevent spam, and ensure that meta is for active, engaged members of the community.

**What is meta?**

Meta is our community for discussing the site itself, including bugs, feedback, and governance issues.

**When should I visit meta?**

- to provide feedback
- to report a bug
- to suggest changes to the community
- to discuss how the site works

**Where is meta?**

There is a link to meta in the footer of every page. The link also appears in the Stack Exchange site switcher (top left in the header) and under the "help" menu (top right in the header).

Our meta naming convention is standard across all sites. The meta site for this site resides at:

https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com